# How does this code for extraction via string methods work?

Tags: python, variables

I have read this code for extraction of data from a website through string methods:

```
def extract_results(data)
     start_index= data.find("<p>")
     while -1 != start_index:
         end_index = data.find("</p>", start_index)
```

Here what is while loop doing? Why start_index is being compared with -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of [`str.find()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) is -1 if the text is not found:

> **`str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`**
>   Return the lowest index in the string where substring *sub* is found, such that *sub* is contained in the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments *start* and *end* are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if *sub* is not found.

The `while` loop effectively makes the code go into an endless loop if `start_index` is not `-1` and is useless unless there is more code following the snippet you shared with us.

Presumably there is something like `return data[start_index + 3:end_index]` as a next line, in which case using `if start_index > -1:` instead of the `while` statement would have been *far* more readable.

It *could* be that `start_index` is set again further down, of course.

Comment: Yes, of course there is more code and much like the one you've written. what does start_index+3 do? I think it'll omit <p>???